# find_elements_by_class_name is not working for some classes

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am new to Selenium using Python. I made some search and still confused about the usage of `find_elements_by_class_name` that doesn't work, as is shown on the attached image.

1. items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('prod_name'), print each item ok.
2. items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('isImpressTs.isImpress'), return 0 show nothing, no error also.
3. items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('isImpressTs isImpress'), return 0 show nothing, no error also.
4. items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('isImpressTs'), return 0 show nothing, no error also.
5. items = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2g4.jpg)/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2g4.jpg)/div[3]/div[2]/dl/dd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2g4.jpg)/dl[2]/dd[3]"), print item ok.

I don't know how to make 2,3 or 4 above work.
XPath works, but how can I find all elements by wildcard instead of specify dd[3] occurrence?

Any help appreciated.

[extract info from this page in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2g4.jpg)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: 2 and 3 are not class names... 2 is a CSS selector (invalid) and 3 is two class names, "isImpressTs" and "isImpress". I don't know why 4 doesn't work without seeing the page. It may be a timing issue... have you tried adding a wait? Have you tried testing these locators in the browser? `$$()` means CSS selector and `$x()` means XPath.

Answer (score 1):

From definition:

```
def find_elements_by_class_name(self, name):
    """
    Finds elements by class name.

    :Args:
     - name: The class name of the elements to find.

    :Returns:
     - list of WebElement - a list with elements if any was found.  An
       empty list if not
```

So, this function returns a list with the same class name.

2-4 ) Change to `items = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.isImpressTs.isImpress')` As you are looking for **a few class names**, not one. `.` is syntax to locate a class.

5 ) Do not use such locators, they are not stable.